# Data source for PageViewController - usage of arrays/dictionaries to store view controllers in data source

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am implementing a scroll style page view controller for my app, based on the page based application template.

In the data source class, I am storing the list of view controllers in a dictionary (could also use array I guess) so that I can reuse them if the user swipes back to a view controller they already viewed. There are about 15 total view controllers in the page view controller.

I wonder if this is a good idea compared to calling the story board  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier each time. (I understand the pageviewcontroller itself stores its own array of view controllers anyway.)

I could instead just store the model object in the dictionary or array and instantiate the view controller and pass in the model object after calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.

I am interested in what is likely to be the better approach.

Comment: also interested if its better to use arrays vs dictionary

Comment: A UIPageViewController does not store a list of all its view controllers. When using the scroll transition, I believe it keeps the current page and the one before and after, but that's all. Unless your load time is very slow, there's no reason to have them all in memory at the same time.